# Fstream won't create file after remove() function - C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I've an fstream file and after I've used remove("file.txt") - which is path of the file created using file.open() - I wanted to create this file again with other content, but the file won't create. What's causing the problem?

Comment: Show code. Show code.

Comment: Edit: nvm, I solved it. Forgot file.close() after opening it for the first time, before removing it.